# Edit not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

When I click it goes to the edit page, when I'm finish editing and click update, it redirects back to a page but the item been edited is not shown back with the updates. But it should redirect back to the page with the updated data. Now nothing returns. This is what I have:

I have edited the question with the controller

```
if (@Model.items.Count > 0)
                            {
                                foreach (var item in @Model.items)
                                {

<div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.expense_acccount, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })                        
                        @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.expense_acccount, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })*@
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.item.expense_account.index, new SelectList(Model.accountlist, "Value", "Text"), new { @class = "form-control" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.expense_acccount, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.item.price, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.item.price, new { @id = "price", @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly", })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.item.price, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>


                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.item.quantity, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.item.quantity, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.item.quantity, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>





                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.item.selecteduomtext)

                @Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.item.lineNum)
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.items)

            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="Update" name="Update" class="btn btn-default" />
                    <input type="button" value="Cancel" name="Cancel" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("IssueItem","Issue")' " class="btn btn-default" />
                </div>
```

**Controller**

```
 private Issue getIssue
    {
        get
        {
            Issue issue = (Issue)Session["Issue"];
            if (issue == null)
            {
                issue = new Issue();
                Session["Issue"] = issue;
            }
            return issue;

        }

    }

public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        getIssue.item = getIssue.items[id - 1];//Returns the requested item for editing
        return View(getIssue);
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the changes submitted from the user and updates the Item in the List  
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="issue"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Issue issue)
    {
        int indx = issue.item.lineNum - 1;
        getIssue.items[indx] = issue.item;

        return RedirectToAction("IssueItem");

    }
```

Comment: Can you provide your Controller Action code that handles the update?

Comment: is that everything you have on your cshtml? maybe you're missing @using?

Comment: You're going to have post more of your code...We need to see the Model, the View, and the Controller in order to help you. The only thing I can see from this code is that if the list count is less than 1 then nothing happens...

Comment: do you not have a `<form>`?

Comment: no i don't have a <form>

Comment: well you need a form that points to that controller action if you are going to post data to it

Comment: i'm using .cshtml

Comment: You still need a form

Comment: i'm not sure if understand what you're saying. Because I already have the edit page and the page that it redirects to with the different headings to store the data; only thing is that it is not showing once it gets back to that page; but the data is shown before it is edited

Comment: You're redirecting to an Action named "IssueItem" but if I'm understanding the problem correctly you need to redirect to an Action that returns a list of items so that you're page can be updated with a new list. Does the Action "IssueItem" return a list or collection of items or does it only return one item? Post the action named "IssueItem". Also zgood is correct your post is missing the form that submits the request. It has to be there unless you're using ajax :)

Comment: @LenriceSujae web browsers have two means available to them for sending data to the server: form posts, and AJAX.  If you aren't using one of those, its hard to communicate with the server.  That's why people say you need a `<form>`

Comment: @BillRuhl it returns a list of items

Comment: Yes I'm using a form; but when click on button update it just redirect to the other page. Without the info

Comment: @zgood is it possible to assist me

Comment: @BillRuhl is it possible to assist me with this question